# Google Charts - Bar chart next to a Line chart, as in Google Trends

Tags: google-visualization

I've search everywhere - how can I make a bar chart next to a [line chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), like they do on [Google Trends](http://t.co/CwqKIlS1Qb)? (I mean the part where they show Interest over time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw two charts, and use CSS to position them in your page however you like.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think that that's what Google did in Trends, I'll try that and update if it works.

Comment: That is what the Trends page does.